# Adding a new bounty on a question that already has a bounty and is newer than 48 hours?

Tags: support, bounties

I want to add another bounty (or increase it) on a question that already has a bounty which is newer than 48 hours.

If this is possible, please explain how?

Comment: Is this a real case? Can you link to the question you're talking about if it is?

Comment: @Catija Here is the link: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/251147/

Comment: @Oded Seems like "can I put a bounty on a question that already has one" should be included in the FAQ... I didn't see it there when I looked at it.

Comment: Oh, the **bounty** is newer than 48 hours... That's what was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in below link it is explained,

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

The question already has a bounty. To start a second bounty on this question, you must wait for the current bounty to be awarded first.